# Trying to reinstall mysql on ubuntu 16.04, unclear error messages, nothing works

Tags: mysql

I am running Ubuntu 16.04 and removed mysql previously. During reinstall I am not sure what happens.

output from terminal

```
ubuntu@ip-my-ip:~$ sudo apt-get install mysql-server
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following additional packages will be installed:
  libcgi-fast-perl libcgi-pm-perl libencode-locale-perl libevent-core-2.0-5 libfcgi-perl libhtml-parser-perl libhtml-tagset-perl libhtml-template-perl libhttp-date-perl libhttp-message-perl libio-html-perl liblwp-mediatypes-perl libtimedate-perl liburi-perl mysql-server-5.7 mysql-server-core-5.7
Suggested packages:
  libdata-dump-perl libipc-sharedcache-perl libwww-perl mailx tinyca
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  libcgi-fast-perl libcgi-pm-perl libencode-locale-perl libevent-core-2.0-5 libfcgi-perl libhtml-parser-perl libhtml-tagset-perl libhtml-template-perl libhttp-date-perl libhttp-message-perl libio-html-perl liblwp-mediatypes-perl libtimedate-perl liburi-perl mysql-server mysql-server-5.7 mysql-server-core-5.7
0 upgraded, 17 newly installed, 0 to remove and 88 not upgraded.
Need to get 0 B/11.1 MB of archives.
After this operation, 96.7 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
perl: warning: Setting locale failed.
perl: warning: Please check that your locale settings:
    LANGUAGE = (unset),
    LC_ALL = (unset),
    LC_CTYPE = "UTF-8",
    LANG = "en_US.UTF-8"
    are supported and installed on your system.
perl: warning: Falling back to a fallback locale ("en_US.UTF-8").
locale: Cannot set LC_CTYPE to default locale: No such file or directory
locale: Cannot set LC_ALL to default locale: No such file or directory
Preconfiguring packages ...
/usr/bin/locale: Cannot set LC_CTYPE to default locale: No such file or directory
/usr/bin/locale: Cannot set LC_ALL to default locale: No such file or directory
Selecting previously unselected package mysql-server-core-5.7.
(Reading database ... 113757 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../mysql-server-core-5.7_5.7.20-0ubuntu0.16.04.1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking mysql-server-core-5.7 (5.7.20-0ubuntu0.16.04.1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libevent-core-2.0-5:amd64.
Preparing to unpack .../libevent-core-2.0-5_2.0.21-stable-2ubuntu0.16.04.1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libevent-core-2.0-5:amd64 (2.0.21-stable-2ubuntu0.16.04.1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package mysql-server-5.7.
Preparing to unpack .../mysql-server-5.7_5.7.20-0ubuntu0.16.04.1_amd64.deb ...
locale: Cannot set LC_CTYPE to default locale: No such file or directory
locale: Cannot set LC_ALL to default locale: No such file or directory
chgrp: cannot dereference '/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock': Permission denied
Unpacking mysql-server-5.7 (5.7.20-0ubuntu0.16.04.1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libhtml-tagset-perl.
Preparing to unpack .../libhtml-tagset-perl_3.20-2_all.deb ...
Unpacking libhtml-tagset-perl (3.20-2) ...
Selecting previously unselected package liburi-perl.
Preparing to unpack .../liburi-perl_1.71-1_all.deb ...
Unpacking liburi-perl (1.71-1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libhtml-parser-perl.
Preparing to unpack .../libhtml-parser-perl_3.72-1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libhtml-parser-perl (3.72-1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libcgi-pm-perl.
Preparing to unpack .../libcgi-pm-perl_4.26-1_all.deb ...
Unpacking libcgi-pm-perl (4.26-1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libfcgi-perl.
Preparing to unpack .../libfcgi-perl_0.77-1build1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libfcgi-perl (0.77-1build1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libcgi-fast-perl.
Preparing to unpack .../libcgi-fast-perl_1%3a2.10-1_all.deb ...
Unpacking libcgi-fast-perl (1:2.10-1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libencode-locale-perl.
Preparing to unpack .../libencode-locale-perl_1.05-1_all.deb ...
Unpacking libencode-locale-perl (1.05-1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libhtml-template-perl.
Preparing to unpack .../libhtml-template-perl_2.95-2_all.deb ...
Unpacking libhtml-template-perl (2.95-2) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libtimedate-perl.
Preparing to unpack .../libtimedate-perl_2.3000-2_all.deb ...
Unpacking libtimedate-perl (2.3000-2) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libhttp-date-perl.
Preparing to unpack .../libhttp-date-perl_6.02-1_all.deb ...
Unpacking libhttp-date-perl (6.02-1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libio-html-perl.
Preparing to unpack .../libio-html-perl_1.001-1_all.deb ...
Unpacking libio-html-perl (1.001-1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package liblwp-mediatypes-perl.
Preparing to unpack .../liblwp-mediatypes-perl_6.02-1_all.deb ...
Unpacking liblwp-mediatypes-perl (6.02-1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libhttp-message-perl.
Preparing to unpack .../libhttp-message-perl_6.11-1_all.deb ...
Unpacking libhttp-message-perl (6.11-1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package mysql-server.
Preparing to unpack .../mysql-server_5.7.20-0ubuntu0.16.04.1_all.deb ...
Unpacking mysql-server (5.7.20-0ubuntu0.16.04.1) ...
Processing triggers for man-db (2.7.5-1) ...
Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.23-0ubuntu9) ...
Processing triggers for systemd (229-4ubuntu19) ...
Processing triggers for ureadahead (0.100.0-19) ...
Setting up mysql-server-core-5.7 (5.7.20-0ubuntu0.16.04.1) ...
Setting up libevent-core-2.0-5:amd64 (2.0.21-stable-2ubuntu0.16.04.1) ...
Setting up mysql-server-5.7 (5.7.20-0ubuntu0.16.04.1) ...
locale: Cannot set LC_CTYPE to default locale: No such file or directory
locale: Cannot set LC_ALL to default locale: No such file or directory
update-alternatives: using /etc/mysql/mysql.cnf to provide /etc/mysql/my.cnf (my.cnf) in auto mode
Renaming removed key_buffer and myisam-recover options (if present)
Job for mysql.service failed because the control process exited with error code. See "systemctl status mysql.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
invoke-rc.d: initscript mysql, action "start" failed.
● mysql.service - MySQL Community Server
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/mysql.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: activating (auto-restart) (Result: exit-code) since Mon 2017-11-27 19:52:02 UTC; 7ms ago
  Process: 16135 ExecStartPre=/usr/share/mysql/mysql-systemd-start pre (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)

Nov 27 19:52:02 ip-my-ip systemd[1]: mysql.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
dpkg: error processing package mysql-server-5.7 (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
Setting up libhtml-tagset-perl (3.20-2) ...
Setting up liburi-perl (1.71-1) ...
Setting up libhtml-parser-perl (3.72-1) ...
Setting up libcgi-pm-perl (4.26-1) ...
Setting up libfcgi-perl (0.77-1build1) ...
Setting up libcgi-fast-perl (1:2.10-1) ...
Setting up libencode-locale-perl (1.05-1) ...
Setting up libhtml-template-perl (2.95-2) ...
Setting up libtimedate-perl (2.3000-2) ...
Setting up libhttp-date-perl (6.02-1) ...
Setting up libio-html-perl (1.001-1) ...
Setting up liblwp-mediatypes-perl (6.02-1) ...
Setting up libhttp-message-perl (6.11-1) ...
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of mysql-server:
 mysql-server depends on mysql-server-5.7; however:
  Package mysql-server-5.7 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package mysql-server (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup error from a previous failure.
                                                                                                          Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.23-0ubuntu9) ...
Processing triggers for systemd (229-4ubuntu19) ...
Processing triggers for ureadahead (0.100.0-19) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 mysql-server-5.7
 mysql-server
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Trying to read the status gives the following:

```
ubuntu@ip-my-ip:~$ systemctl status mysql.service
    ● mysql.service - MySQL Community Server
       Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/mysql.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
       Active: inactive (dead) (Result: exit-code) since Mon 2017-11-27 19:52:04 UTC; 54s ago
      Process: 16248 ExecStartPre=/usr/share/mysql/mysql-systemd-start pre (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)

    Nov 27 19:52:04 ip-my-ip systemd[1]: mysql.service: Control process exited, code=exited status=1
    Nov 27 19:52:04 ip-my-ip systemd[1]: Failed to start MySQL Community Server.
    Nov 27 19:52:04 ip-my-ip systemd[1]: mysql.service: Unit entered failed state.
    Nov 27 19:52:04 ip-my-ip systemd[1]: mysql.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
    Nov 27 19:52:04 ip-my-ip systemd[1]: mysql.service: Service hold-off time over, scheduling restart.
    Nov 27 19:52:04 ip-my-ip systemd[1]: Stopped MySQL Community Server.
    Nov 27 19:52:04 ip-my-ip systemd[1]: mysql.service: Start request repeated too quickly.
    Nov 27 19:52:04 ip-my-ip systemd[1]: Failed to start MySQL Community Server.
```

I have tried reinstalling, purges, auto cleans, auto remove. but nothing worked.

Comment: I think https://askubuntu.com/ is a better choice for this question.

Comment: there seems to be something off with your locales. try fixing that